# Windows 10, window.open() is taking over parent window incorrectly. Works fine in Windows 7/8

Tags: popup, windows-10, fullscreen

I have a web application where people can check-in for activities they are attending for the day.  If the person has a message waiting, the message will appear in a small popup box over the top of the parent window. You still see the parent window in the back, but the popup is on top for action. When the person has read the message, they click to close the popup and the parent remains for them to complete their check-in.

The popup has worked for years in all browsers and all operating systems.  For some reason, in Windows 10, it is now 'taking over' the parent window completely. It isn't a small box anymore...it takes the full screen of the parent window.  Thus when the person clicks to close the popup window, it is closing the entire app.

The function I use for the popop:

```
function popupmsg(url)  {
  params  = 'width=600';
  params += ', height=300';
  params += ', top=150, left=200'
  params += ', scrollbars=no'
  params += ', resizable=no'
  params += ', menubar=no'
  params += ', location=no'
  params += ', status=no'
  params += ', titlebar=no'
  params += ', toolbar=no'
  params += ', fullscreen=no';`

  var newwin=window.open(url,'popupmsg', params);
  if (window.focus) {newwin.focus()}
  return false;
}
```

It is called in the parent html using the following function on the body load

```
function membermessage() {
    popupmsg('msgpopupck.do?');
}
```

In the html:

```
<body onLoad="javascript:membermessage();">
```

Has anyone run into this in windows10? or anywhere?